# Javaでのwavファイル結合について

Tags: java

```
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(binaryData1);
        bis.close();
        fis.close();
        fis = new FileInputStream(file2);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(binaryData2);
        bis.close();
        fis.close();

        byte[] outputBinary = new byte[(int)(binaryData1.length+binaryData2.length-44)];
        System.arraycopy(binaryData1,0, outputBinary, 0, binaryData1.length);
        System.arraycopy(binaryData2,44, outputBinary, binaryData1.length, binaryData2.length-44);

        int fileSize = outputBinary.length-8;
        outputBinary[4]=(byte)(fileSize & 0xff);
        outputBinary[5]=(byte)((fileSize >>> 8)&0xff);
        outputBinary[6]=(byte)((fileSize >>> 16)&0xff);
        outputBinary[7]=(byte)((fileSize >>> 24)&0xff);

        int fileData = outputBinary.length-44;
        outputBinary[4]=(byte)(fileData & 0xff);
        outputBinary[5]=(byte)((fileData << 8)&0xff);
        outputBinary[6]=(byte)((fileData << 16)&0xff);
        outputBinary[7]=(byte)((fileData << 24)&0xff);
```

２つのwavファイルを結合させるプログラムを作っているのですが、一つ目の音声ファイルを再生し終えると再生が止まってしまいます。ファイルデータの更新がないことに気がついたのですが、どのように直したらいいでしょうか。

Comment: 参考情報: [Join two WAV files from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653861/join-two-wav-files-from-java)

Answer (score 3):

fileData の方、シフトの向きが逆なのと、書き込み位置が間違ってますね。

```
    outputBinary[40]=(byte)(fileData & 0xff);
    outputBinary[41]=(byte)((fileData >> 8)&0xff);
    outputBinary[42]=(byte)((fileData >> 16)&0xff);
    outputBinary[43]=(byte)((fileData >> 24)&0xff);
```